# Swagger different definitions for JSON and XML

Tags: json, xml, swagger, openapi

I'm currently documenting an API with Swagger 2.0.

The API produces `application/json` and `application/xml`.

The definition section is this:

```
definitions:
  newsFeed:
    type: object
    description: the object is wrapped...
    properties:
      feedId:
        type: string
        example: '987654'
        xml:
          attribute: true
      title:
        type: string
      description:
        type: string
      feedUrl:
        type: string
        example: http://heise.de.feedsportal.com/c/35207/f/653902/index.rss
      logoUrl:
        type: string
        example: http://example.com/logo.png
      language:
        type: string
        example: de_DE
      pos:
        type: string
        example: '0'
      active:
        type: boolean
```

Swagger-UI generates this XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<newsFeed feedId="987654">
    <title>string</title>
    <description>string</description>
    <feedUrl>http://heise.de.feedsportal.com/c/35207/f/653902/index.rss</feedUrl>
    <logoUrl>http://example.com/logo.png</logoUrl>
    <language>de_DE</language>
    <pos>0</pos>
    <active>true</active>
</newsFeed>
```

And this JSON:

```
{
  "feedId": "987654",
  "title": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "feedUrl": "http://heise.de.feedsportal.com/c/35207/f/653902/index.rss",
  "logoUrl": "http://example.com/logo.png",
  "language": "de_DE",
  "pos": "0",
  "active": true
}
```

Both is correct, but the API deliveres a different JSON.

```
{
    "newsFeed": {
        "feedId": "987654",
        "title": "string",
        "description": "string",
        "feedUrl": "http://heise.de.feedsportal.com/c/35207/f/653902/index.rss",
        "logoUrl": "http://example.com/logo.png",
        "language": "de_DE",
        "pos": "0",
        "active": true
    }
}
```

How can I document this with Swagger?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent xml-wrapper element in Swagger-ui](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43104791/113116).

Comment: The Problem is the same, thank you for the link, but the suggest solution is not acceptable. The benefit of OpenAPI/Swagger is a machine and human readable documentation. Without specifying the properties of an object one would lose the complete machine part for testing with Swagger-UI or other tools.
So it looks like we have to wait until OpenAPI 3.0 is finished and all tools have been updated :(